# Interpolating CFD data in 2D using griddata MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to find residuals of my solutions. However, each solution uses a different grid, thus I would like to interpolate the solutions in 2D to a mesh grid for each solution such that I can easily find the residuals.

I used griddata which seems to work, but it doesn't work very well in regions of discontinuities and near edges. I would like to interpolate data of flow over a sphere for example. The area of the sphere should be confined to zero since that is outside of the grid boundaries; however, after using griddata, there's some non zero values in the sphere region. I also get a warning saying there were duplicate x and y points.

Does anyone know how to preserve the integrity of the sphere after using griddata? I've double checked the original x,y data, and the area of the sphere all have values of 0.

Thank you. I hope that made sense.

Best,

Yuki

Comment: Have a look at the [`scatteredInterpolant class`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolantclass.html) - it might suit your problem better.

Comment: I'm using an older version of MATLAB. I can't get a copy of the newer version so I can't use the scatteredInterpolant class. I've been thinking that I've been getting this problem because of the duplicated points. I tried to use unique to get rid of duplicated points but when I executed griddata, it still says that I have duplicated points. Any info on this?

Comment: How old is your version? Do you have [`TriScatteredInterp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triscatteredinterp.html)?

Comment: Yes, I used it, and I still got non zero values in areas that should be 0.